# Approval Process Reassign Functionality Not Changing Record Owner

Tags: apex, force.com, approval-process

The '**Reassign**' functionality for the Approval Requests does not change the '**Owner**' of the record. It only the changes the '**Actor**' field for the '**ProcessInstanceWorkitem**'

Is there any way I can change the **Owner** field on the record while the request is Reassigned to  a different user?

Comment: The Approval Process usually locks the record until the Approval Request is accepted or rejected, which could cause you some issues with trying to change the owner

Comment: But is there any way we can capture the Reassign event. Something like a trigger being invoked. Or any hack.

Comment: I don't believe that triggers can be added to the Approval Request record.

Answer (score 1):

The owner is irrelevant from an approval record point of view. Only the actor matters. You can't change the owner, so there's really no point in trying.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how your Approval Process is configured, you could set a field update on the owner ([here is a SFDC Success Article with a walk-thru](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hJbSAAU)).

There are 3 problems I see with this:

1. I don't believe the Field Update would know to dynamically set the Owner Value equal to the newly Assign Approver, so you would need to set the order of who it's assigned to ahead of time.
2. I have not used a multiple step approval process (Request Approval -> Approver 1: Approves -> Approver 2: Approves -> Approved), so I'm not 100% sure that allows field updates for each step.
3. As @sfdcfox says, the actor only matters for the approval record. It's hard to imagine a scenario the record getting approved should change owners, but I've seen stranger things.